# Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()' using Twitter sdk

Tags: android, twitter, android-gradle-plugin

I now there some other guys, which asked for this kind of problem, but all this solutions doesn't worked for me. I only added the twitter sdk's an nothing else in the Project.
Please help me

> Android gradle build Error:(9, 0) Gradle DSL method not found:
>   'compile()'.

Getting Error "Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'" when Syncing Build.Gradle

My `build.gradle` code is here

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {


        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
            compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.1.1'
            compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-mopub:3.1.1'
            compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.1.1'
            compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-ui:3.1.1'
            compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-composer:3.1.1'
            compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-mopub:3.1.1'

        }

    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()

        }
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First build.gradle

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 26
        buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.twitter.ratz.william.test"
            minSdkVersion 19
            targetSdkVersion 26
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
        compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta3'
        compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.1.1'
        compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-mopub:3.1.1'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
```

Second build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you mess between your root `build.gradle` and application's `build.gradle`.

As minimum you should remove `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'` from `dependencies { ... }` of your application’s Gradle config (usually `app/build.gradle`).
Then you should check your root `build.gradle`. It should look like:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files

    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Then you will need to add the following dependencies to your application’s Gradle config (usually `app/build.gradle`) as wrote in the [official docs](https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/android/installation)

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.1.1'
  compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-mopub:3.1.1'
}
```

Comment: You have as minimum 2 `build.gradle` files. Could you post the second  `build.gradle`?

Comment: Thanks man you solved my problem. The problem was that I don´t had a second build.grade (don't know why). So I builded a new project and it worked, i will post the hole code.